# git merge sanity check

Tags: git, git-merge

Developer A is working on branch 2012A

I branch 2012A, and create branch 2012B

I want all the new changes from 2012A, so I simply want to merge them into 2012B and carry on working.

Does this look ok as a workflow?

```
git checkout 2012A (switch to 2012A)
git pull origin 2012A (update 2012A)
git checkout 2012B (switch to 2012B)

git merge 2012A (merge in 2012A)
git commit -m 'commiting changes from 2012A' (commit changes from 2012A in 2012B)
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work, however you could do it in a simpler way:

**directly from branch `2012B`**:

```
git fetch origin
git merge origin/2012A
```

---

Note that you are not required to have a local branch for `2012A`: if have a repository in your *remotes* (here your remote is `origin`) you usually carry the snapshots of the remote branches. You can see them by running:

```
git branch -a
```

(See the `remotes/...` entries of the output)

The `git fetch` command updates the snapshots, so `git fetch origin` updates your local images of the remote branches in `origin`, and `git merge origin/2012A` merges such image into the current branch (i.e. applies the patches of `origin/2012A` on `2012B`).

---

Suggested article: 
http://longair.net/blog/2009/04/16/git-fetch-and-merge/